# How do I query firebase to get child data to use in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database of the following structure:

```
database
    field1
        -KkXawoXnSCInWXugbm-
            email: "email1@email.com"
            firstName: "John"
            lastName: "Smith"
            phoneNumber: "123456"
            password: "password1"
    field2
        -KkXanaeY4pWSl2Aqltt
            email: "email2@email.com"
            firstName:"Jane"
            lastName: "Doe"
            phoneNumber: "5550123"
            password: "password2"
```

In my Android project, I have a login screen with an Email and a password. I have a User abstract class that has two child classes, field1 and field2.

```
public abstract class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String userID; //this is the Firebase generated key as seen above
    private String password;
}
```

What I want to do is use the email to find the node representing that user and access the rest of their details so that I can verify the information entered in the Login page.

I'm a beginner at Firebase and have searched extensively for a way of doing this but have been unable to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What `-KkXanaeY4pWSl2Aqltt` means, UUID? It would be better if it is, else searching large database will be slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this. What i recomand you to do is to change the node from `UID` to email `address`. In this way you'll have all you need to query. But because Firebase does not accept `.` symbol in the key i recomand you encript the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, i have changed the `.` in `,`. To do this, i recomand you using this methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I did this and my database is now of the following form: 
field1
        email: "email1@email.com"
            firstName: "John"
            lastName: "Smith"
            phoneNumber: "123456"
            password: "password1"
But dataSnapshot.getValue(field1.class) now returns a null value, how do I fix this?

Comment: If youdr `DatabaseReference` is set on the `userId` than you need to use the String class like this: `String email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look into fields for eg. Field1. 
Then you can simply use the following query.

```
ref.child("field1")  //only useful if you are having multiple nodes in field1
     .orderByChild("email")
     .equalTo("your_email_query")
```

Using this DataSnapshot you can query other details.
Hope this works!!